# Creating a new iOS application from an existing iOS application

Tags: ios, xcode, app-store, appstore-approval, mobile-development

I got a good app source code which I want to extend its functionality and make a new app in the store, Can I do that and get it approved?

If I can do so what is the steps I should follow, I cloned the source code, Should I make an new Xcode project and copy the files to it? or I can change the Bundle Id or I don't have to?

Comment: This question shouldn't be asked here. But yes, you can get it approved and you have to change the bundle id.

Comment: Just create a new target and assign it a different bundleID.

Comment: Thank you where it should be asked? @sasquatch

Comment: I'm voting to close this question because app store submission policy is [off-topic for Stack Overflow](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/272165/65839) and better addressed by Apple support.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about an app store's policies and procedures, rather than programming. See [Are developer-centric questions about application stores on topic?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/272165)